# My Css file isnt loading in my Asp.Net MVC 2 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I added some css to the default css file to put css in one of my view pages but its not loading

```
<ul id="timeline">
 <% foreach (var update in Model.Updates)
    { %> 
  <li>
  <div class="message"> .......
```

css I put in the default file is

```
#timeline {list-style: none; padding:0;}
#timeline li {border-top: dashed 1px #888; padding: 5px 0;}
#timeline li:hover {background: #eee;}
#timeline li div.message {font-size: 10pt;}
#timeline li div.message span{font-weight: bold;}
#timeline li div.time {font-size: 8pt; font-style:italic;}
```

I am using vs2010 on my home laptop...any ideas?

Comment: Either you made a typo in your code insert above or you really have forgotten to put a # in front of 'timeline' for each of those rules. 'timeline' with no hash wouldn't target anything in the HTML.

Comment: thats a typo, i have the #timeline for every line and it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in this [live demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/S4fjc/1/) the CSS and the supposed HTML markup work fine. So you have either:

- HTML that doesn't match the CSS rules
- The CSS file is not found/included in your application because you specified a wrong path to it

In any cases [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) could be very useful in diagnosing this types of problems.